# Get first part of a domain from a string in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I've looked on SO already but all the solutions like to use URI, when it isn't required I want to do this in regex so I made my own post because the other posts are different.

I want to extract usernames from a url, so lets say I have urls like below.

```
https://godisgod123.example.com/post/294912194919491
sunrises.example.com/profile/29491294919
http://imsorry.example.com/video/12932993113
```

I would get

```
godisgod123
sunrises
imsorry
```

What have I tried already?

```
return Regex.Match(address, @"^\w*\.\w*\.\w*").Value;
```

But the above code doesn't work, it returns an empty string.

Comment: All answers use URI, I advise you to read questions before answering them.

Comment: the possible duplicate answers use not just the URI class (for cause), but also things like a dedicated NPM package, a regex solution, and an extension method (extending the URI class but could be implemented as a standalone method). Additionally URI based answers, could be mined for the parts dealing with a string, as all cast the host to a string then work it. I see this as a duplicate question, because I see it as asking for the same answers (just w/o the URI class), but there's a reason why it takes multiple votes to close a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\w` matches all word characters, which does not include `://`. Your regex expects an optional sequence of word characters up to a literal `.`, but there's a `://` in between the word characters and the `.`, which means there's no match for your first and third examples.

Your second example matches the full domain, which is better but still not what you want.

In order to satisfy the requirements of your specific example, you can use a simple regex, like this:

```
(\w+)\.
```

This matches a group (`()`) of word characters (`\w`), followed by a . (`\.`). In order to just extract the group of word characters (the subdomain), you can access the group using this C# code:

```
Regex.Match(address, @"(\w+)\.").Groups[1]
```

Note the following:

1. There's no testing for `null` here, so you'll want to ensure you're handling the case when there are no matches.
2. This doesn't work when there are multiple subdomains. For example, with `one.two.example.com`, it will match only `one` instead of `one.two`.
3. It also doesn't work for subdomains that include non-word characters. e.g. `one-two.example.com` will match only `two` instead of `one-two`.

This satisfies the requirements of your question, but it's not very robust for at least the reasons I've stated above. The URI approach is likely going to handle this better, but I felt it was worth explaining the regex option here.

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression is probably an overkill for this - A simple use of `IndexOf` and `Substring` will do just fine. In fact, I've been using an extension method that extracts a substring between two delimiters for a few years now:

```
public static string Substring(this string source, string fromDelimiter, string toDelimiter)
{
    var start = source.IndexOf(fromDelimiter);
    if (start == -1)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("fromDelimiter", fromDelimiter + " not found in " + source);
    }

    start += fromDelimiter.Length;
    var end = source.IndexOf(toDelimiter, start);

    if (end == -1)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("toDelimiter", toDelimiter + " not found in " + source + " after " + fromDelimiter);
    }

    return source.Substring(start, end - start);
}
```